# Setters and getters across multiple classes? CPP

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm having some trouble on my homework trying to figure out how I can use a setter function from my base class in a derived class. I'm not sure if I worded that correctly as I'm new to C++, but hopefully my code can explain it better!

```
class account{
private:
    double balance;

protected:
    int numwithdraws = 0;

public:
    void Setbalance(int bal)
    {
        balance = bal + balance;
    }
    int Getbalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }
};

class checking : public account {
public:
    WriteCheck(int checknum,double amount)
    {
        cout<<"Check amount?"<<endl;
        cin>>amount;
        Setbalance(amount);
        checknum++;
    }
};
```

Inside my main function there's an option to make a withdrawal, usually that would mean my balance would go down so I'd have to figure out how to make this negative in my setbalance later, but

```
    checking obj2;
    obj2.WriteCheck(0,0);
    cout<<"New Balance = "<<obj1.Getbalance()<<endl;
```

I took out a lot my code to narrow down where the problem point is, but I'll try to explain it better in words if what I wrote down for my code is confusing.

What I have in my base class account are a **Setbalance** and a **Getbalance**. In my derived class **checking** I'm trying to use the **Setbalance** function that's in my base class in my derived class function **WriteCheck** to change the amount of my private variable **balance** which is in my account base class.

The problem is when I use the Setbalance in my derived class function and call my Getbalance in main, it still ends up 0 and doesn't change the amount in variable balance.

I'm getting confused reading my own explanation, so I understand if it's hard to grasp what I'm trying to ask. If that's the case, please let me know so that I can try and explain further!

Comment: You don't seem to be initializing `balance` anywhere. If so, then `SetBalance` has UB when it reads from `balance`.

Comment: There's no problem calling a base class method from a derived class, it's a perfectly common thing to do. So whatever problem is causing this issue, it's not that.

Comment: You called `SetBalance` correctly, but your code doesn't make sense. You either cut out too much for the example or need to rethink it. In your sample, `GetBalance()` is expected to return `0`, so there is no issue here. I also recommend using a debugger to find out exactly what your code does.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with what you're trying to achieve (calling a function in the base class from within the derived class). A derived class will generally have the functions that the base class has, so calling

```
checking obj2;
obj2.Getbalance()
```

Is perfectly fine. I made some syntax changes to your code so it can run. The only major change I made was set `balance` to 0 so there wouldn't be any undefined behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class account {

private:
    double balance = 0;

protected:
    int numwithdraws = 0;

public:
    void Setbalance(int bal)
    {
        balance = bal + balance;
    }
    int Getbalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }
};

class checking : public account
{
public:

    void WriteCheck(int checknum, double amount)
    {
        cout << "Check amount?" << endl;
        cin >> amount;
        Setbalance(amount);
        checknum++;
    }
};

int main()
{
    checking obj2;
    cout << "New Balance = " << obj2.Getbalance() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you so much! I was able to fix my code up. Appreciate you taking the time to help me out! My brain was hurting trying to figure out what I was doing wrong or even if I was doing anything wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: @ZeeJay: Thanks for the feedback. Please don't forget to mark my response as accepted answer for your question!